# stop the event-listener operate while using website surfing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dictionary

I like using the oxford dictionary site.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/loudly?q=loudly
Here is the website url when i searched a certain word, 'loudly'.

Hmm.. I'm chrome user and I also use a chrome-dictionary addon.

The feature of the dic-addon is that I can readily search a word just double click any words, then addon automatically find out what is mean by showing the little popup view located on the upper left corner of chrome browser.

The problem is, like the dic-addon, oxford dictionary site offer the same double click service.

In oxford dic site, if you just double click any words for search the meaning of word through chrome dic addon, suddenly they pick me up to a site where shows the definition of word that i double clicked, and addon's searching result page was canceled due to moved site url. How annoying.. :(

But I want to use only chrome dic addon double click feature.
And the more worse, I can't give up the use of oxford dictionary...

So.. There is any breakthrough to ignore the double click event in dictionary website?

Comment: Do you want to stop the behaviour of the website or the addon? Which addon are you using?

Comment: The behavior of the website ! And my using addon is.. this _ https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%EB%84%A4%EC%9D%B4%EB%B2%84-%EC%98%81%EC%96%B4%EC%82%AC%EC%A0%84-naver-english-di/jfibpeiddefellcfgnijpcpddoimbdij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the developer tools (F12) on a page of http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/ and they type `$('.main-container').off('dblclick');` and hit enter this will disable oxfordleanersdictionaries double click feature. However this will need to be done each time you load a page.

If you know how to make Chrome Extensions you could create one that calls this code each time a www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com page is visited. Alternatively install something like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=ko) and add this line to a custom script.

I created a tampermonkey script with the following code and it works perfectly

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.main-container').off('dblclick');    
}, 1000);
```

Run at in the settings was set to document-end

Comment: Wow, ingenious idea ! Thanks !!